# What is a best way to make web-app look like an android's one?

Tags: javascript, android, html

Basically I'm asking whether there is such an option to make html based app appear like it wasn't running on a browser. Maybe some nice and handy way to turn it into fullscreen or simply make url bar disappear, or maybe even magically fully-transform webapp into browserless one (I wish life was that easy) ?

Comment: sounds like you want a Progressive Web App. [Learn more here](https://web.dev/progressive-web-apps/)

Comment: PWAs can be a pain to set up properly if you don't know what you're doing, but you can use a manifest.json file to specify display mode if a user saves the webpage as an "app" to their phone's home screen.  Same end result as a PWA but without a lot of the hassle and headache.